# Working with XMLtable columns . Is it possible to assign collection datatypes to xmltable columns

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, xquery, xmltable

I have a requirement where I have to select XML table columns into a record datatype which is a combination of static data types and collection. I searched various sources that said Xpath can return a list of nodes, but I doubt whether I can use collection datatype for columns to store this list of nodes.

```
  type MobileTable is Table of number Index by pls_integer; 

    type purchase is record (vegetables varchar2(20),fruits varchar2(30));
 
    type food is table of purchase Index by pls_integer;
     type data is record
    (Name varchar2(30), Mobile_Number MobileTable,Purchases food);
 


    <customers>
    <month>July</month>
    <day>Tuesday</day>
    <start-time>11</start-time>
     <customer>
    <Name>sally</Name>
    <Mobile-Number>999-256-00</Mobile-Number>
    <Mobile-Number>999-256-11</Mobile-Number>
    <purchase>
    <vegetables>Carrot</vegetables>
    <fruits>Apple</fruits>
    </purchase>
    <purchase>
    <vegetables>Broccli</vegetables>
    <fruits>Orange</fruits>
    </purchase>
    <customer>
    </customers>
```

The about XML is just an example I took to explain my requirement, please do suggest if the question is not clear.

my query:

```
    select Name,Mobile_Number,Purchases into  data from custommers_table ct,
      xmltable('customers' 
        passing ct.cust_xml
        columns Name varchar2(20) path 'Name',
                Mobile_Number MobileTable path 'Mobile-Number',
                Purchases food path '//purchase/vegetables|//purchase/fruit')
where cust_xml_id=1;
```

I am getting an invalid datatype error in the case of Mobile_Number and Purchases.

`//purchase/vegetables|//purchase/fruit`

I found this XPath in W3 schools under the Xpath syntax concept, I am not sure about its correctness but that is what I want to achieve.

Please suggest if there are any other ways I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As a fairly brute-force approach, you could get the mobile numbers and purchases as child xmltype variables, and populate the collections in loops:

```
declare
  type t_mobile_numbers_tab is table of varchar2(15) index by pls_integer; 

  type t_purchase_rec is record (
    vegetables varchar2(20),
    fruits varchar2(30)
  );
  type t_purchases_tab is table of t_purchase_rec index by pls_integer;

  type t_data_rec is record (
    name varchar2(30),
    mobile_numbers t_mobile_numbers_tab,
    purchases t_purchases_tab
  );

  l_data t_data_rec;
  l_mobile_numbers xmltype;
  l_purchases xmltype;
begin
  select name, mobile_numbers, purchases
  into l_data.name, l_mobile_numbers, l_purchases
  from custommers_table ct
  cross apply xmltable('customers/customer' 
    passing ct.cust_xml
    columns name varchar2(20) path 'Name',
            mobile_numbers xmltype path 'Mobile-Number',
            purchases xmltype path 'purchase/vegetables|purchase/fruits'
  )
  where cust_xml_id=1;

  for r in (
    select mobile_number
    from xmltable('Mobile-Number'
      passing l_mobile_numbers
      columns mobile_number varchar2(15) path '.'
    )
  )
  loop
    l_data.mobile_numbers(l_data.mobile_numbers.count) := r.mobile_number;
  end loop;

  for r in (
    select type, purchase
    from xmltable('*'
      passing l_purchases
      columns type varchar2(10) path 'name(.)',
              purchase varchar2(30) path '.'
    )
  )
  loop
    if r.type = 'vegetables' then
      l_data.purchases(l_data.purchases.count).vegetables := r.purchase;
    elsif r.type = 'fruits' then
      l_data.purchases(l_data.purchases.count).fruits := r.purchase;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The first query gets the scalar name and two child xmltype values. Those xmltype variables are then used in cursor queries, and in those cursor loops the numbers/purchases are extracted and assigned to records within the child collections.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6d5ddab80cf41c0f14783f27cc321811) showing the intermediate values, and also printing out the contents of the collections to see what was populated.

This would be a bit simpler with object types rather than records; but still feels like there might be a more efficient approach.